# Javascript typecasting has weird behaviours when order of operands change

Tags: javascript, casting

I was just writing some javascript code and noticed a really weird behaviour when doing simple arithmetic operations.

Consider the following code:

```
let anyNumber = 10;
anyNumber = anyNumber + (12.512).toFixed(2); // toFixed() returns a String
console.log(anyNumber); // it will output 1012.512

// By changing the Order of the operands, there is no difference in operation and it basically concatenates both as a string.

let anotherNumber = 10;
anotherNumber = (12.512).toFixed(2) + anotherNumber;
console.log(anotherNumber);  // output 12.5110
```

The code block will print `1012.512` as a string because it is understandable that one of the operands was a String. But we slightly modify the situation, as stated below:

```
console.log((12.512).toFixed(2) + 10); // it will output 22.51

// Also if we change the order here, the output is very different.

console.log(10 + (12.512).toFixed(2)); // It will output 1012.51
```

The question is, if we change the order of the operands in an expression, it detects the change and behaves very differently but in case of variables, it doesn't differentiate in anyway even though the typeof the variable `anyNumber` is still a `number`

Comment: weird, `console.log((12.512).toFixed(2) + 10);` must return 12.5110

Comment: Same, I can't reproduce your `console.log` output. What browser or node version are you getting that from ?

Comment: This code is being used in NodeJS so, it's not about browser compatibility. Node version is 12.13.0.

Comment: Another thing is that ```console.log("11">10);``` outputs ```true``` while ```console.log("10">10);``` outputs ```false```. It is as if it knows the type even though it shouldn't be this way.

Comment: You  can use other arithmetic operations,  -, /, * between a string and a number, they will all evaluate as if both are numbers.